# Reflection com propriedade list

Tags: c#, reflexão

Como é possível alterar o valor da propriedade da classe na lista?

Minha variável `classPropValueList` sempre vem nula.

Estou tentando fazer uma *reflection* de toda classe que herda de `Coisable`, para alterar suas propriedades do tipo string.

É possível encontrar as seguintes propriedades em uma classe que herda de `Coisable`:

1. Uma propriedade do tipo string (que deverá ser alterada)
2. Uma propriedade do tipo de alguma outra classe que também herda de `Coisable` (essa classe deverá ter suas propriedades do tipo string alteradas, então tem-se aqui a necessidade do uso de recursividade).
3. Uma propriedade do tipo coleção de alguma outra classe que também herda de `Coisable`, e para cada um dos itens da coleção, suas propriedades do tipo `string` devem ser alteradas.

Consegui então, através do código abaixo, resolver o cenário 1 e 2, mas tive problemas com o 3º cenário. Ao *debugar* o código, vi que no caso de exemplo, é possível entrar na terceira condição, mas ao tentar obter a lista, ela sempre vem nula.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var coisa1 = new MyClass3
        {
            MyProperty1 = "Valor Original 1",
            MyProperty2 = new MyClass1
            {
                MyProperty = "Valor Original 2"
            },
            MyProperty3 = new List<MyClass2> 
            {
                new MyClass2 
                {
                    MyProperty = "Valor Original 3"
                }
            }
        };

        Console.WriteLine("--- Valores Originais ---");
        Console.WriteLine(coisa1.MyProperty1);
        Console.WriteLine(coisa1.MyProperty2.MyProperty);
        Console.WriteLine(coisa1.MyProperty3.First().MyProperty);

        Console.WriteLine();

        coisa1.Coise();


        Console.WriteLine("--- Novos Valores ---");
        Console.WriteLine(coisa1.MyProperty1);
        Console.WriteLine(coisa1.MyProperty2.MyProperty);
        Console.WriteLine(coisa1.MyProperty3.First().MyProperty);

    }
}

// #region Minhas Classes

    public class Coisable
    {
    }


    public class MyClass1 : Coisable
    {
       public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass2 : Coisable
    {
       public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyClass3 : Coisable
    {
        public string MyProperty1 { get; set; }
        public MyClass1 MyProperty2 { get; set; }
        public List<MyClass2> MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    }

    // #endregion

    // #region Reflection

    public static class CoisableExt
    {
        public static void Coise(this Coisable coisableClass) {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in coisableClass.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if(typeof(string).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
                {
                    var propValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(coisableClass, null).ToString();
                    propValue = "Novo Valor";
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(coisableClass, propValue, null);
                }
                else if(typeof(Coisable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
                {
                    var classPropValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(coisableClass, null) as Coisable;
                    classPropValue.Coise();
                }
                else if (typeof(IEnumerable<Coisable>).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType))
                {
                    var classPropValueList = propertyInfo.GetValue(coisableClass, null) as List<Coisable>;
                    if(classPropValueList != null && classPropValueList.Any())
                    {
                        classPropValueList.ForEach(classPropValueItem =>
                        {
                           classPropValueItem.Coise();
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // #endregion
```

Comment: Tem como explicar um pouco melhor o que pretende? Da forma atual é preciso ler todo o código pra tentar entender o problema

Comment: Editei a pergunta, adicionando mais alguns detalhes...

Comment: Aliás, duas notas: 1. gostei do nome da classe (`Coisable`); 2. Muito bom criar um [mcve], ótima ideia.

Comment: Eu sinceramente não sei se foi um elogio ou um puxão de orelha, haha...

Comment: Foram dois elogios =D É bom ter um código que só é preciso copiar e colar pra rodar e poder entender os problemas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema aqui é que você não pode converter uma lista de objetos de um determinado tipo para uma lista de objetos do tipo base.

Experimente fazer isto sem *reflection*, algo como:

```
var listaMyClass = new List<MyClass2>(); 
var listaCoisable = listaMyClass as List<Coisable>;
```

O compilador irá avisar que este tipo de conversão não é possível e é por isso que a variável `classPropValueList` recebe `null` ao invés do valor esperado.

Isso é uma questão de *design* da linguagem, escolheram que seria assim e existem motivos para isso. [Você pode ver nesta resposta o que o Eric Lippert fala sobre isto.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1817341/4190610)

Em contrapartida, é possível fazer esta conversão usando um `IEnumerable` e depois converter pra uma lista usando Linq. Ainda seria possível fazer um *cast* usando o método apropriado pra isto, mas aí seria necessário mais *reflection* ainda.

Particularmente, eu acho que a ideia de usar um `IEnumerable` é uma boa saída pro seu caso.

Então, apenas troque o `as List<Coisable>` por `as IEnumerable<Coisable>` e depois use o `ToList()` para converter a sequência para uma lista.

```
var classPropValueList = (propertyInfo.GetValue(coisableClass, null) 
                            as IEnumerable<Coisable>)?.ToList();
```

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7NcWwD).

Comment: muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente aqui, mas acima de tudo, pude entender melhor o motivo e o funcionamento. Só tive que fazer algumas alterações, pois estou usando o .Net 4.0 em um projeto legado, ao invés do Roslyn usado em seu Fiddle.

Comment: Ah, sim. Mas você pegou o essencial, né. Converter o código é só uma validaçãozinha, coisa secundária mesmo.